# Create graph from dicts python

Tags: python

I  have dicts

```
{'IMG_0003_1.tif': ['IMG_0004_1.tif', 'IMG_0005_1.tif'], 
'IMG_0004_1.tif': ['IMG_0005_1.tif', 'IMG_0003_1.tif'], 
'IMG_0005_1.tif': ['IMG_0004_1.tif', 'IMG_0006_1.tif'], 
'IMG_0006_1.tif': ['IMG_0007_1.tif', 'IMG_0005_1.tif'], 
'IMG_0007_1.tif': ['IMG_0006_1.tif', 'IMG_0008_1.tif'], 
'IMG_0008_1.tif': ['IMG_0009_1.tif', 'IMG_0007_1.tif'], 
'IMG_0009_1.tif': ['IMG_0008_1.tif', 'IMG_0010_1.tif'], 
'IMG_0010_1.tif': ['IMG_0009_1.tif', 'IMG_0011_1.tif'], 
'IMG_0011_1.tif': ['IMG_0012_1.tif', 'IMG_0013_1.tif'], 
'IMG_0012_1.tif': ['IMG_0011_1.tif', 'IMG_0013_1.tif'], 
'IMG_0013_1.tif': ['IMG_0014_1.tif', 'IMG_0012_1.tif'], 
'IMG_0014_1.tif': ['IMG_0013_1.tif', 'IMG_0015_1.tif'],
'IMG_0015_1.tif': ['IMG_0014_1.tif', 'IMG_0016_1.tif'], 
'IMG_0016_1.tif': ['IMG_0017_1.tif', 'IMG_0015_1.tif'], 
'IMG_0017_1.tif': ['IMG_0019_1.tif', 'IMG_0018_1.tif'], 
'IMG_0018_1.tif': ['IMG_0019_1.tif', 'IMG_0017_1.tif'],
'IMG_0019_1.tif': ['IMG_0018_1.tif', 'IMG_0017_1.tif'],
'IMG_0020_1.tif': ['IMG_0021_1.tif', 'IMG_0022_1.tif'],
'IMG_0021_1.tif': ['IMG_0020_1.tif', 'IMG_0022_1.tif'], 
'IMG_0022_1.tif': ['IMG_0023_1.tif', 'IMG_0021_1.tif'], 
'IMG_0023_1.tif': ['IMG_0022_1.tif', 'IMG_0021_1.tif']}
```

key - image
value - list of neighbor images
How create graph from this dicts with python networkx?
this will be used for stitching images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [from_dict_of_lists](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.convert.from_dict_of_lists.html#networkx.convert.from_dict_of_lists):

```
import networkx as nx

d = {'IMG_0003_1.tif': ['IMG_0004_1.tif', 'IMG_0005_1.tif'],
     'IMG_0004_1.tif': ['IMG_0005_1.tif', 'IMG_0003_1.tif'],
     'IMG_0005_1.tif': ['IMG_0004_1.tif', 'IMG_0006_1.tif'],
     'IMG_0006_1.tif': ['IMG_0007_1.tif', 'IMG_0005_1.tif'],
     'IMG_0007_1.tif': ['IMG_0006_1.tif', 'IMG_0008_1.tif'],
     'IMG_0008_1.tif': ['IMG_0009_1.tif', 'IMG_0007_1.tif'],
     'IMG_0009_1.tif': ['IMG_0008_1.tif', 'IMG_0010_1.tif'],
     'IMG_0010_1.tif': ['IMG_0009_1.tif', 'IMG_0011_1.tif'],
     'IMG_0011_1.tif': ['IMG_0012_1.tif', 'IMG_0013_1.tif'],
     'IMG_0012_1.tif': ['IMG_0011_1.tif', 'IMG_0013_1.tif'],
     'IMG_0013_1.tif': ['IMG_0014_1.tif', 'IMG_0012_1.tif'],
     'IMG_0014_1.tif': ['IMG_0013_1.tif', 'IMG_0015_1.tif'],
     'IMG_0015_1.tif': ['IMG_0014_1.tif', 'IMG_0016_1.tif'],
     'IMG_0016_1.tif': ['IMG_0017_1.tif', 'IMG_0015_1.tif'],
     'IMG_0017_1.tif': ['IMG_0019_1.tif', 'IMG_0018_1.tif'],
     'IMG_0018_1.tif': ['IMG_0019_1.tif', 'IMG_0017_1.tif'],
     'IMG_0019_1.tif': ['IMG_0018_1.tif', 'IMG_0017_1.tif'],
     'IMG_0020_1.tif': ['IMG_0021_1.tif', 'IMG_0022_1.tif'],
     'IMG_0021_1.tif': ['IMG_0020_1.tif', 'IMG_0022_1.tif'],
     'IMG_0022_1.tif': ['IMG_0023_1.tif', 'IMG_0021_1.tif'],
     'IMG_0023_1.tif': ['IMG_0022_1.tif', 'IMG_0021_1.tif']}

G = nx.from_dict_of_lists(d)

for edge in G.edges:
    print(edge)
```

**Output** *(partial)*

```
('IMG_0003_1.tif', 'IMG_0004_1.tif')
('IMG_0003_1.tif', 'IMG_0005_1.tif')
('IMG_0004_1.tif', 'IMG_0005_1.tif')
('IMG_0005_1.tif', 'IMG_0006_1.tif')
('IMG_0006_1.tif', 'IMG_0007_1.tif')
('IMG_0007_1.tif', 'IMG_0008_1.tif')
('IMG_0008_1.tif', 'IMG_0009_1.tif')
('IMG_0009_1.tif', 'IMG_0010_1.tif')
('IMG_0010_1.tif', 'IMG_0011_1.tif')
('IMG_0011_1.tif', 'IMG_0012_1.tif')
('IMG_0011_1.tif', 'IMG_0013_1.tif')
```